# How do I limit Java Web Start to Java 6 without Java 7 support

Tags: java, jnlp, java-web-start

We have a legacy medical application which gets deployed using Java web start however, when  user attempts run the application on Internet Explorer it installs Java 7. The application does not support Java 7. So, I have attempted to force the application to use Java 6 Update 30 but have encountered several problems with install Java using the Java ActiveX plugin and Internet Explorer 6. Consistently, it just did not work. The page would assume Java was installed because a plugin developed Microsoft would confuse it.

So, attempt 2. Bypass the plugin and redirect the user to the Java download website, http://java.sun.com/webapps/getjava/BrowserRedirect?host=java.com&returnPage=. Problem, when Java 7 is installed the page redirects back to return page.

Arrrg....

So, I need another solution. Please help.

Details
Java Versions 
1.6.0_update10 - 1.6.0_update30.

Browsers
Internet Explorer: 6 - 10
Firefox: 3 - 7

Answer (score 1):

See [Java Web Start - Runtime Versioning](http://pscode.org/jws/version.html).  The version elements can be restricted to a particular release.

Comment: There are a couple problems with your solution: (1) The web start XML configuration only allow a lower range. It does not allow you specify a upper range. (2) What happens if you don't have java? You just download a jnlp file?

Comment: Aside from that, there is currently a bug preventing some users from downloading Java 6 automatically via JNLP j2se versioning. They would have to do so manually. Oracle really broke webstart with Java 7 and I don't think they care much about it as they just released "7 update 5" and STILL no fix for webstart issues.